# DAX for Grouping

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have following data set as data Model.

```
    Country          City         AssetCount                              
      USA         Newyork           50                                
      USA         Washington        40
      USA         California        30

     India        Bangalore          100
     India        Delhi             50
     India        Bombay            30
```

I want to show one row showing sum of Assetcount at country level & city level on the same row.

There are two slicers for slicing City & Country as below:

```
USA        Newyork        
India      Washington    
           California    
           Bangalore    
           Delhi        
           Bombay
```

So when I select country as India it should show sum of Asset-Count at country(India) level.
In the same way when I select City as Delhi it should show Asset-Count at City(Delhi) level.

```
   India      Delhi
    180        50
```

Is it possible using PowerPivot using DAX?

Related content from their question on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9265edda-6ce7-4599-8a69-6be8225a729a/dax-for-grouping?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel)

Actually your solution is not working. I have created the hierarchy as Country-->City & kept that in Rows. So when I select a particular Country & City it showing like this:

```
Row Labels           AssetCount
USA                      40
Washington               40
Grand Total              40
```

But I want

USA      Washington
   120           40

or may be like

```
USA                  120
Washington           40
```

I have tried some aggregate functions like below:

=SUMX(VALUES(Query[City]),CALCULATE(SUM(Query[AssetCount])))

=CALCULATE(SUM(Query[AssetCount]),SUMMARIZE('Query',Query[City]))

Here Query is table for Data Model & City can be replaced by Country.
 but not working.

So showing such counts on same row is possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are just getting started with Power Pivot.  You might browse through the links on [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/power-pivot-add-in-HA101811050.aspx#_Toc262226429) for more help.

I took the data you provided and pasted it into Excel.

1. Selected the data and clicked Add to Data Model and checked the box for My Data Has Headers.
2. I made sure the AssetCount Column had a data type of whole number. Then clicked the Pivot Table button and created a pivot table on my existing spreadsheet.
3. I put AssetCount in the values and made sure it was set to Sum in the Field Value Settings.
4. I selected my pivot table and then went to the Analyze tab under PivotTable Tools and clicked the Insert Slicer button.
5. I selected both Country and City as slicers.

This gives your desired result. [image]

Comment: May be You didn't get my question. Please follow my same question on MSDN.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9265edda-6ce7-4599-8a69-6be8225a729a/dax-for-grouping?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel

Comment: Ah, so you are saying you want to see both the country and City on the same line when you select a city. Ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two numbers in a row, that's pretty straightforward. Keep in mind, that all those slicers do is putting filters on the pivot table.

Therefore to get your city result, you could use either an implicit measure or explicit measure that simply sums up AssetCount.

For the country result, you'd wish to overload the city filter like this:
=calculate(SUM(Query[AssetCount]),ALL(Query[City]))

If you also need the country and city names there, it gets a bit tricky.